# can an entity exist in isolation in ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

can an entity exist in isolation in ER diagram? When this entity has no relation ship with other entities (they have relationship with others) in the diagram?

Will this diagram be a valid ER diagram?

Answer (score 0):

There's no rule that all entities in an ER diagram must be related, but unrelated subgraphs of an ER model can be seen as logically distinct database schemas. I would question why you want to show them together in a diagram if they have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you mean **entity type** here. In the academic aspect of the ER diagrams, they represent a mini-world and there are no rules that entity types should be related in the mini-world. Example: in a **"school"** mini-world, you might have a **student** entity type and **invoice** entity type, they can't be related but they are parts of the mini-world **school**.